# Regex: Test for custom URLs

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting, preg-match

I have a site where users can create their own profile pages with their own Custom URLs. For example: `http://www.website.com/MyProfilePage` or `http://www.website.com/JohnnysPage`

I need a regular expression that only allows **a-Z 0-9** and **-** (hyphens). No spaces or other characters.

So, for example it would...

**FAIL ON THESE STRINGS**

```
http://www.website.com/MyProfilePage 
My Profile Page 
My.Profile.Page 
My_Profile_Page 
My/Profile/Page 
Katie'sPage
```

etc. etc.

**PASS ON THESE STRINGS**

```
MyProfilePage
KatiesPage
MyProfilePage
Davids-Page
TheBestPage-2001
```

etc. etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say simply:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$
```

Comment: you need to escape the hyphen `\-`

Comment: @AndreasWinter: No, it's not mandatory in a character class when it's at the begining or at the end.

Comment: @M42, it may lead to unexpected errors if you forget that when extending the pattern.

Comment: @Alp: Yes it may. But it's a habit of mine to not write unnecessary characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$/',$string)
```

Answer (score 2):

[preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to the rescue:

```
$pattern = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$/';
$match = preg_match($pattern, "My.Profile.Page"); // returns false
$match = preg_match($pattern, "MyProfilePage"); // returns true
```

**[Working demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XZQFn8)**